# Statement requires expression of integer type ('double' invalid)

Tags: c++, switch-statement, double

I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double score;


    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "Enter your grade score and I will give you a letter grade \n";
    cin >> score;

    if (score < 0 || score > 100)
        cout << "Enter a number less than 100 and greater than 0" << endl;

    switch (score)
    {
        case score > 90 :
            cout << score << "Grade: A";
        case score > 80 || score < 90  :
            cout << score << "Grade: B";
        case score > 70 || score < 80  :
            cout << score << "Grade: C";
        case score > 60 || score < 70  :
            cout << score << "Grade: D";
        case score < 60 :
            cout << score << "Grade: F";

    }
}
```

I kept getting

> Statement requires expression of integer type ('double' invalid)

How can I debug this further?

Comment: Find introductory material on `switch`.

Comment: Hint: That's not how `switch` works.

Comment: There is a typo. I'm sorry. I know how switch case work, but I don't write in c++ a lot. I need help.. why do I get this error ? -->


`Statement requires expression of integer type ('double' invalid)`

Comment: @chris : plz removed your downvote. It's was a typo paste in by accident.

Comment: @NickyC : plz removed your downvote. It's was a typo paste in by accident.

Comment: The typo you fixed doesn't change my recommendation. Also, your assumption about me is incorrect.

Comment: Stop making false assumptions, both when you write program, and when you interact with people. Instead, properly learn how things work.

Comment: In addition to the other tips - when you rewrite this using `if` you should also consider that `score < 60` and `score > 60` misses one point - exactly 60.

Comment: **Don't** make edit that changes the question fundamentally.

Comment: use a `if-else` instead of `switch` case

Comment: Also you would suffer from fallthrough even if all the above worked.

Comment: Note that the use of `||` is also wrong. A score of 75 would output `B` instead of `C`, for example.  The code would need to use `&&` instead of `||`, eg: `score >= 90`, `score >= 80 && score < 90`, `score >= 70 && score < 80`, and so on.  But the `&&` would be redundant when using `if/else` blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You CANNOT use a floating-point data type in a `switch` expression, only integral and enumeration data types.

You CANNOT use a boolean expression in a `case` statement, it MUST be a compile-time integer/enum constant value.

In short, you are *completely* misusing `switch`.

If you want the user to enter a floating-point value, then you MUST use something else, such as `if/else`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double score;

    cout << "Enter your grade score and I will give you a letter grade \n";

    if (!(cin >> fixed >> setprecision(2) >> score))
        cout << "Invalid input! Must be an integer or decimal number" << endl;

    else if ((score < 0.0) || (score > 100.0))
        cout << "Invalid score, must be a number between 0 and 100, inclusive" << endl;

    else if (score >= 90.0)
        cout << "Grade: A" << endl;

    else if (score >= 80.0)
        cout << "Grade: B" << endl;

    else if (score >= 70.0)
        cout << "Grade: C" << endl;

    else if (score >= 60.0)
        cout << "Grade: D" << endl;

    else
        cout << "Grade: F" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you MUST use `switch`, then you CANNOT use a floating-point type, you MUST to use an integral type instead, just like the error message says.  But then you have to write a separate `case` for *every individual integer value*, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int score;

    cout << "Enter your grade score and I will give you a letter grade \n";

    if (!(cin >> score))
        cout << "Invalid input! Must be an integer number" << endl;

    else if ((score < 0) || (score > 100))
        cout << "Invalid score, must be a number between 0 and 100, inclusive" << endl;

    else
    {
        switch (score)
        {
            case 100:
            case 99:
            case 98:
            case 97:
            case 96:
            case 95:
            case 94:
            case 93:
            case 92:
            case 91:
            case 90:
                cout << "Grade: A" << endl;
                break;

            case 89:
            case 88:
            case 87:
            case 86:
            case 85:
            case 84:
            case 83:
            case 82:
            case 81:
            case 80:
                cout << "Grade: B" << endl;
                break;

            case 79:
            case 78:
            case 77:
            case 76:
            case 75:
            case 74:
            case 73:
            case 72:
            case 71:
            case 70:
                cout << "Grade: C" << endl;
                break;

            case 69:
            case 68:
            case 67:
            case 66:
            case 65:
            case 64:
            case 63:
            case 62:
            case 61:
            case 60:
                cout << "Grade: D" << endl;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Grade: F" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which is not desirable when you have to deal with ranges, so you are likely going to end up using `if/else` anyway to write shorter, efficient code.

`switch` is not always the best way to go.

Comment: I have to use switch case. Sorry. Not of else.

Comment: Then either your requirements are unreasonable, or you have misunderstood them.  You CANNOT use a `double` with a `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're insist of using a `switch` case instead of a `if else` code will be something like this. But for your information, due to your insist of using a `switch` case the code have added additional few line of codes into it while if is an `if else` you are able to wrote it within **single line of code**

```
int main()
{
    double score;
    char grade;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "Enter your grade score and I will give you a letter grade \n";
    cin >> score;

    if (score < 0 || score > 100)
        cout << "Enter a number less than 100 and greater than 0" << endl;
    else
    {
        if(score > 90)
            grade = 'A';
        else if(score > 80 || score < 90)
            grade = 'B';
        else if(score > 70 || score < 80)
            grade = 'C';
        else if(score > 60 || score < 70)
            grade = 'D';
        else if(score < 60)
            grade = 'F';

        switch (grade)
        {
            case 'A' :
                cout << score << "Grade: A";
            //case 'B', case 'C' so and so on...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `switch` is useless in this example, because you could just do a single `cout << "Grade: " << grade;` after determining the value of `grade`.  Also, see my other comment about the misuse of `||`, use `&&` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just noticed that, thanks for reminding. I was just writing on my text editor without compiling it. Yes, indeed the `switch` is an useless example. At last, we are trying to optimize the program (even if it's a small one) and why we need to wrote extra line to achieve the same goals/objective while we are able to do it with a single line of code.

Comment: the reason of I wrote the "useless" `switch case` due to this comment **"I have to use switch case. Sorry. Not if else."**

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch), the condition of the switch statement may be:

> any expression of **integral or enumeration type**, or of a class type contextually implicitly convertible to an integral or enumeration type, or a declaration of a single non-array variable of such type with a brace-or-equals initializer.

As `double` is not an integral type (it is a floating point type), it cannot be used in a switch statement. You don't even need it anyway, if you want your user to enter only integer grades. The other bug you have is that each of your case statements will fall through to the `case` below without a corresponding `break`. Thus, you should add a `break` statement to each of your `case` statements as well.

Comment: what would be the `break` case do ?

Comment: Basically, in switch statements, you need a break after every case to actually _leave_ the switch statement after the current check. If you remove the break, code execution ends up in the case directly below (If there is one), and this is known as a fallthrough. The link in my answer goes over fallthrough as well.

Comment: got it. I was confuse with the default case. yes, will add that.

Comment: should I change my double to int ?

Comment: @ihue Yup, If you need to check the values of doubles, then you will have to use an if statement. Otherwise change the type of the variable to int and leave the switch as is. (Adding the break as well).

Comment: Change to int, got this `Case value is not a constant expression`

Comment: I updated my post with your suggestion. I don't know what esle to do ?

Comment: @ihue, You don't put a condition in the case statement, you put just the number. So like `case 90:`. (Sorry I'm replying so late, I had left for the night after posting this answer). However, you should probably prefer an if statement for this kind of program, since now with a switch statement, you will have to list every kind of grade that warrants the same letter.